Laravel feature test with redirecting middleware
I am using laravel 9.X, i have created Feature Test cases.
There is a middleware on route
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'location', 'middleware' => 'adminAuth'), function () {

  Route::get('/', 'LocationController@index');

});


adminAuth ->if valid user found ,redirect to dashboard.


LocationController@index -> return status 200.

now when i run test for "LocationController@index"
it returns 302.
how to check for assert status 200?

The feature test is being redirected, therefore it does not receive a status 200. You should create a test case that acts as an admin (and assert status 200) and a test case that acts as a normal user (and assert status 302).

middleware is created such that if admin then redirect to dashboard if normal user redirect to home page.

i just want to bypass middleware so that i can check route response.

Does this answer your question? How to Disable Selected Middleware in Laravel Tests

kind of , i have to do it with little modification.
Thanks.
